# Show message defined in other component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

So I have this template part at the moment:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="arrayWithItems">
    <tr class="item" (click)="child.toggleActive()" #child [item]="item" item-component>
    <tr class="detail" *ngIf="item.details && !item.errmsg" [details]="item.details" detail-component>
    <tr class="detail" *ngIf="item.errmsg">
        <td colspan="3">
            <p>{{ item.errmsg }}</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

When a user clicks on the `item-component`, the `item-component` retrieves the details of the item (using a service) and sets it to `item.details`. Because `item.details` is then set, it shows the `detail-component` (`*ngIf` is true). However I want that whenever something goes wrong (like invalid json returned), it shows a message. The problem I'm facing: the message is defined in the `item-component`.

How can I make this work the way I want? Please note that `Item` is a model. So `item.errmsg` as I have it now doesn't work. I'd like an alternative method besides adding the `errmsg` key to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the component the variable `#child` already. You can use that in your template to access the `item-component`.

```html
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="arrayWithItems">
    <tr class="item" (click)="child.toggleActive()" #child [item]="item" item-component>
    <tr class="detail" *ngIf="item.details && !item.errmsg" [details]="item.details" detail-component>
    <tr class="detail" *ngIf="child.errmsg">
        <td colspan="3">
            <p>{{ child.errmsg }}</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Oh... I thought I could only use that in the child elements -_- . Ah well, need more coffee anyways. Thanks!